# vertically integrate a datasheet with a over 1500 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, spatial-data-frame

I have a data sheet with about 1700 columns and 100 rows of data w/ a unique identifier.  It is survey data and every employee of an organization answer the same 9 questions but its compiled into one row of data for every organization.  Is there a way in python/pandas to vertically integrate this data as opposed to the elongated format on the x-axis it already is at? I am cutting and pasting currently.

Comment: So each row consists of blocks of 9 cells, each for an employee. And now you want to reshape your data into 9 columns by whatever number of rows?

Comment: thanks for replying, actually its 100 rows (100 organizations), and 1 long row of 9 survey questions per employee in the organization.  so if there are 24 employees per organization there are 216 columns of questions with data in it, if 100 employees then 900 columns etc.  if there is a way to automate/reorganize the data vertically as opposed to one long horizontal row, that'd be amazing

Answer (score 1):

You can `reshape` the underlying numpy array and reindex with proper companies:

```
# sample data, assuming index is the company
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(36).reshape(2,-1))

# new index
idx = df.index.repeat(df.shape[1]//9)

# new data:
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,9), index=idx)
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17
1  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
1  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35
```

Comment: ok thanks, I'm slowly getting what's going on here. So where you have 'DataFrame'  do I need to enter my 'z' regarding my path below ?  Or do I need to convert my csv to an array or another format?  Thank you for this tip               z = open('/Users/test/Documents/NonProfit/NonProfit_Survey.csv', encoding="Latin-1")